# Application open url is not working in ios 9.2. why?

Tags: ios, openurl

I need to open facebook page in native App by using open url fb:// It doesnt work in ios 9.2 please help!

Comment: What did you tried so far? Please edit your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, In iOS 9 you must whitelist any URL schemes your App wants to query in Info.plist under the  key `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes'

[image]

This may help you.